# Can't add controller in Visual Studio Express 2015 for web

Tags: visual-studio

I just installed Visual Studio Express 2015 for Web and I wanted to follow this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-controller

The problem is, when I want to add controller, I am not able to select it. 
[Weird](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtgHY.png)

How can I resolve this bug?

Thanks.

Comment: Happened to me once. I'm not sure exactly what fixed it, but try making sure you are using correct project template / framework version and that correct versions of assemblies are referenced. Also try to compile the project before going to Add.

Comment: Okay, I built it first. But then I noticed that I was in debuggind mode and then I stopped debugging mode. After that I can add. Ok, case closed then. Thanks anyway